# Cannot read property length of undefined array error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, undefined

I am using the code below to get a list of colours used by 3 divs. If this div has a color set, then it should be pushed into the array `checkColors`.

```
var checkColors = [];

$("div[style]").each(function(){
    getColor = $(this).css("color");
    if(getColor){
        checkColors.push(getColor);
    }
});

if(checkColors){
    checkColors = shuffleArray(checkColors);
    if(checkColors.length > 0){
        if(checkColors[0]){
            backgroundColor = checkColors[0];
        }
        if(checkColors[1]){
            primaryColor = checkColors[1];
        }
        if(checkColors[2]){
            secondaryColor = checkColors[2];
        }
    }  
}
```

However, `if(checkColors.length > 0){` gives me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error which I don't understand since I have an If statement to check whether or not the array is undefined.

Here is the `shuffleArray()` function:

```
    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if(checkColors){` is always true.

Comment: how does your `shuffleArray()` look like?

Comment: Clearly, calling `shuffleArray` is resulting in `undefined`, which is getting assigned to `checkColors`. It's probably missing a `return xyz`, but since you haven't shown it...

Comment: `if(typeof(checkColors) !== "undefined)` would be better than just `if(checkColors)`

Comment: @scrappedcola: `if (checkColors)` is just fine, but as Jonas pointed out above, in the given code it'll always be true. (Also: `typeof` is an operator, not a function. No more need to put its operand in `()` than any other operator.)

Comment: @Kristianmitk It doesn't return any errors but when I check the console after shuffleArray(), it just says undefined. Get color does have values

Comment: @Phiter Sorry! Just added it in

Comment: Well, indeed there is no "return" in shuffleArray function, the shuffle array mutates the array and does return nothing.

Comment: @Pac0 Thanks! Working now

Answer (score 4):

I guess that

```
 shuffleArray(checkColors)
```

mutates the array instead of returning a new one. Therefore

```
 checkColors = shuffleArray(checkColors)
```

will set shuffleArray to undefined.

Comment: Stop upvoting. I dont deserve reputation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are already manipulating the array inside shuffleArray, do not assign it again to checkColors.

Below code change should work -

```
// checkColors = shuffleArray(checkColors);
// replace above line with
shuffleArray(checkColors);
```

Otherwise you need to return an array from shuffleArray if you are assigning it to checkColors.

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
   // your code
   // after for loop
   return array;
}
```